# 404 page not found: error while running localhost//ci/ in codeigniter 3/1/2

Tags: codeigniter, runtime-error

I am a beginner in `codeigniter 3.1.2`.

While I am running `localhost//ci` it shows `404 page not found` error. *`ci` is my folder name*.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you got your wamp server running? Do you need to specify a port for your localhost? Have you checked the htaccess file? Checked your config file for default route? Is it the codeigniter 404 error page? Need more details.

Comment: apche, mysql is running.

Answer (score 0):

May be you gets 404 error because of Controller.

Defining a Default Controller

*CodeIgniter can be told to load a default controller when a URI is not present, as will be the case when only your site root URL is requested. To specify a default controller, open your `application/config/routes.php` file and set this variable:*

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'blog';
```

Where ‘blog’ is the name of the controller class you want used. If you now load your main index.php file without specifying any URI segments you’ll see your “Hello World” message by default.

For more information, please refer to the “Reserved Routes” section of the [URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) documentation.

or may be there .htaccess problem
check link for more https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/404-page-not-found-the-page-you-requested-was-not-found-codeigniter-project/223800